# how to set mode: 'open' when creating a shadow element using vue-custom-element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, shadow-dom

this is how I created a shadow element

```js
Vue.customElement('my-element', MyElement, {
  shadow: true,
  shadowCss: mystyles,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `options.shadow=true` causes [`vue-custom-element` to set `mode` to `open`](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element/blob/324dbac/src/utils/registerCustomElement.js#L8-L9). Since your code is doing that, your custom element would already have an open shadow root.

Comment: I recommend asking that as a new question so that someone familiar with the topic could provide an answer.

Comment: How can include vuetify custom theme, when shadowRoot is open?